# Exclude word(s) from App Store searches

Tags: ios-appstore

How can I exclude words from searches in iOS App Store?

An example query could be like this:

`monopoly -bingo`

would avoid matches with `bingo` from turning up in results when searching for `monopoly`.

This doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

How about leveraging a *better* search engine to accomplish the same task?

Use [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)

[image]

Hit **Advanced Search** button and you get this:

[image]

Or directly type this in Google search bar:

`monopoly -bingo site:itunes.apple.com`

I'm not sure if doing a Web search will take into account the keywords associated with the app as supplied by the developer (as you may be intending to include/exclude them).

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever with Google. Find it to be a decent enough Web search engine and recommend it for use (best used in incognito mode, without logging in).